# Loading a Recurrent Neural Network Tensorflow | Error: Exception encountered when calling layer "my_model"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using tensorflow and python to try and generate a quote using a recurrent neural network. I've successfully trained my model and I saved the model, no errors, but when I try to load the model in another script I get a long error message. The model is saved to a folder with other subfolders and .pb files. If anyone could tell me what you think is wrong that would be great. Thanks!

Error message:

```
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "my_model" "                 f"(type MyModel).

    Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * <tf.Tensor 'inputs:0' shape=(1, None) dtype=int64>
        * None
        * True
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}

     Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):

    Option 1:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='inputs')
        * None
        * False
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}

    Option 2:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='inputs')
        * None
        * False
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}

    Option 3:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
        * None
        * False
        * False
      Keyword arguments: {}

    Option 4:
      Positional arguments (4 total):
        * TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100), dtype=tf.int64, name='input_1')
        * None
        * False
        * True
      Keyword arguments: {}

    Call arguments received by layer "my_model" "                 f"(type MyModel):
      • args=('tf.Tensor(shape=(1, None), dtype=int64)',)
      • kwargs={'states': 'None', 'return_state': 'True', 'training': 'False'}
```

Here's my code for loading the model (this is probably the root of the problem):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

path_to_file = tf.keras.utils.get_file('data.txt', 'file:///C:/Users/sebas/Desktop/quites/data.txt')
text = open(path_to_file, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
vocab = sorted(set(text))
ids_from_chars = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(vocab), mask_token=None)
chars_from_ids = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary(), invert=True, mask_token=None)

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('quoteModel')
class OneStep(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars, temperature=1.0):
    super().__init__()
    self.temperature = temperature
    self.model = model
    self.chars_from_ids = chars_from_ids
    self.ids_from_chars = ids_from_chars
    skip_ids = self.ids_from_chars(['[UNK]'])[:, None]
    sparse_mask = tf.SparseTensor(
        values=[-float('inf')]*len(skip_ids),
        indices=skip_ids,
        dense_shape=[len(ids_from_chars.get_vocabulary())])
    self.prediction_mask = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_mask)

  @tf.function
  def generate_one_step(self, inputs, states=None):
    input_chars = tf.strings.unicode_split(inputs, 'UTF-8')
    input_ids = self.ids_from_chars(input_chars).to_tensor()
    predicted_logits, states = self.model(inputs=input_ids, states=states,
                                          return_state=True)
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits[:, -1, :]
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits/self.temperature
    predicted_logits = predicted_logits + self.prediction_mask
    predicted_ids = tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)
    predicted_ids = tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)
    predicted_chars = self.chars_from_ids(predicted_ids)
    return predicted_chars, states

one_step_model = OneStep(new_model, chars_from_ids, ids_from_chars)
start = time.time()
states = None
next_char = tf.constant(['I'])
result = [next_char]

for n in range(1000):
  next_char, states = one_step_model.generate_one_step(next_char, states=states)
  result.append(next_char)

result = tf.strings.join(result)
end = time.time()
print(result[0].numpy().decode('utf-8'), '\n\n' + '_'*80)

print(one_step_model.generate_one_step("I"))
```

Comment: Too much code..maybe provide a minimal reproducible example and leave out the rest?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I pared down the model loading code and I removed the code for training the model, as I don't think that's the root of the problem.